# In React Router, how do you pass route parameters when using browser history push?

Tags: react-router

Using the newer version of React Router, how do you pass parameters to the route you are transitioning to if you are transitioning using the browserHistory.push()? I am open to using some other way to transitioning if browserHistory does not allow this. I see that in my top most child component in React Router there is this.props.routeParams but I can't seem to get this populated with values I want from the previous route when transitioning.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Now you will have do something like this

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/about',
  search: '?the=search',
  state: { some: 'state' }
})
```

Here is the link for [API documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md)

Comment: inside the `location` object obtained from the props

Comment: on next page access state using this.props.location.state.some

Comment: Is this still valid in React Router V4 ?

Answer (score 3):

for react router v4 we can do things this way:

```
const history = useHistory();
 history.push({
      pathname: "/create-opinion/"+user,
      state:{  username:userName}
    };
```

and to get it from the other component simply:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

then to get username:

```
const username = history.location.state.username;
```

don't forget to import useHistory from react-router-dom

if you haven't install react-router-dom
yet type:

```
$ npm install --save react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a path parameter you can do it as follows. I am using sample component *Merchant*.

**Define Route**

```
<Route exact path="/merchant/:id" render={(props) => <Merchant id={props.match.params.id}/>} />
```

**Define History**

```
const history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename:''
})
```

**Add to history with parameter**

```
history.push(`/merchant/${id}`)
```