# How do you programmatically update URL params in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-parameters

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678804/in-react-router-how-do-you-pass-route-parameters-when-using-browser-history-pus) doesn't quite cover it since it appears that you have to pass a reconstructed URL into `pathname`

If I am on the child page of these routes:

```
  <Route name="Parent" path="/parent/:parentId" component={Parent}>
    <Route name="Child" path="/child/:childId" component={Child}>
```

how do I programmatically update the `:parentId` without having to re-construct the entire URL?

Something along the lines of `history.push({ ...., params: {parentId: 'newParent'}})` would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: asked same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130682/change-react-router-route-params-programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you programmatically update query params in react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161516/how-do-you-programmatically-update-query-params-in-react-router)