# Change react router route params programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there any simple and convenient way to navigate to same route with different params?

for ex. I'm right now on /profile/idan and I wish to change the param of `idan` to something else, instantly without dealing with the static part of the route.

Comment: Is this v3 or v4?

Answer (score -2):

If your question is about v3 of the API, the `react-router` library introduces a `router` context. If you declare that in your `contextTypes`, you'll have access to a [push](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) and [replace](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#replacepathorloc) method. Example:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { PropTypes as RouterPropTypes } from 'react-router';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  // ...
  handleSomeEvent() {
    this.context.router.push('/some/url');
  }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: RouterPropTypes.routerShape
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: It's v3, and actually `push` is what I don't like to use because I can't switch the params, I have to specify the whole route, which my main question is how to avoid it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. They explicitly removed support for things like that. You may want to look at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1840 for context. Essentially the solution is "build your own," and use the low-level push mechanism. There is no functionality for route URL building.